Cost of emails for CiviEmail
How much does it cost to send emails on civi? I'm trying to find the rates of emails and I can't find anything anywhere

Already answered via chat. It totally depends on your hosting situation. If your server can send emails in bulk properly with full set up of SPF, DKIM and DMARC to avoid poor reputation and bounces, then the answer could be nothing.
If you opt to send through a 3rd party service then depends on what service you use

CiviCRM includes tools to create and send e-mail(ing)s but the actual process of delivering all e-mails to recipients is done by a tool. And to have a successful behaviour it is recommended to use something called a SMTP Gateway that is a server dedicated to sending e-mails. If you send few messages, you could avoid setting one or paying for such a service. If you often send campaign and aren't a sysadmin, it's going to be difficult to avoid paying for such a service. We own our servers but we work with a dedicated French company that provides us with a SMTP gateway. You can find many of them on the market. And what you pay is related to the volume.
So CiviCRM is cost free to send e-mailing but deliverability has a cost.

I'm finding hosting companies put limits on emails per hour and really don't like mass emails going out at all. Obviously if your site is on a shared server and someone is sending out spam then the whole server and it's clients get blacklisted. Not good. I now recommend using something like SendGrid, which is reliable and does not cost too much. All the heavy work is offloaded to them.
